# Traditional and modern approaches to class field theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, function-fields, big-picture

I read in Gerald Janusz's book *Algebraic Number Fields* where he says there are two approaches to class field theory. The **traditional** approach, as in his book, uses L-series, Dirichlet density and  Frobenius density theorem, to prove the surjectivity of the Artin map. Then with only a little bit of cohomology without talking about ideles one can prove Artin reciprocity, conductor theorem, classification of abelian extensions etc.

I also found many other books, for example the one by Cassel Frohlich, that avoid analysis technique and prove these theorems by systematically using cohomology and ideles classes. I guess this is the **modern** approach to class field theory.

I wonder **what are some pros and cons for these two approaches**. For example, the traditional approach won't require many advance algebra techniques and the modern approach is more insightful(for example, we define Brauer group with cohomology). Plus, I guess the modern approach is more generalizable, for example to function fields. But I cannot find many useful resources on class field theory on function fields. **Is there any references?** Thank you.

Comment: The old Artin-Tate notes, from c. 1951?